# How to make carousel caption responsive? I have added image and code in description box please look over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While testing on a small device, the carousel caption is not appearing properly. Please check the image I have added.

[Screenshot of large device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giH1e.png)

[Screenshot of small device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh6XV.png)

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="image/ramya-carusel.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Field irrigation">
    <div class="carousel-caption  col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-8">
      <h1>Experience Real Life Quality in Offset and Digital Printing.</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="image/ramya-carusel.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Field irrigation">
    <div class="carousel-caption col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-8">
      <h1>Experience Real Life Quality 
        in Offset and Digital Printing.</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="image/ramya-carusel.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Field irrigation">
    <div class="carousel-caption col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-8">
      <h1>Experience Real Life Quality 
        in Offset and Digital Printing.</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Write some css rules for the media you are targeting.

Comment: i have added css  
.carousel-caption{
  background-color: rgba(248, 244, 244, 0.5);
  color:black;
  opacity: 10;
  right: 40%;
  left:10%;
  height:60%;
}

Comment: Add `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .carousel-caption h1 { font-size : 20px; } }` etc.

Comment: Omg wonderful,it is working,but there is button right it is coming out of box. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `.carousel-caption` CSS rules to adjust the elements size so that it appears in the view port clearly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
     {    .carousel-caption {
          bottom: 50px !important;
          }
          .carousel-caption h1 { 
          font-size : 20px !important; 
          }
     }
```

The above CSS will change the font-size of h1 element to 20px for the devices which maximum width is 768px. The CSS class `.carousel-caption` is positioned absolute so, increase the `bottom` to higher if it doesn't fits you.